# Is a function probability generating function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, generating-functions

If $f(s)=s+(1-s)^2\times \log (1/(1-s))$ is a probability generating function? My calculations show that it is not.

Comment: $f(s)=2s-\frac{3}{2}s^2+\ldots$ so $f'(0)=2$ $f''(0)=-3/2$ and so on.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Thank you for your comment!